# How can I calculate the average of the random numbers in a grid?

Tags: javascript

I have a random grid generator that asks how big you want the grid. If you input `5` it will produce a `5x5` grid with random numbers in it, or a `10x10` grid with random numbers etc.

I now need to take those random numbers once the grid is produced and display the average of the random numbers. I can't seem to get this part to work, because there are different numbers each time you generate a new grid.

```js
var button = document.getElementById('gridSize');

button.onclick = function(e) {
  result = document.getElementById('wrapper');
  num = parseInt(document.getElementById('grid').value);
  var str = "<table border='2'>";

  for (row = 0; row < num; row++) {
    str += "<tr>";
    for (col = 0; col < num; col++) {
      var randNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
      if (randNumber % 3 === 0) {
        str += '<td style="background: red;">';
      } 
      else if (randNumber % 2 === 0 && !randNumber % 3 === 0) {
        str += '<td style="background: blue;">';
      } 
      else {
          str += "<td>";
      }

      str += randNumber + "</td>";
    }
    str += "</tr>";
  }
  str = str + "</table>";
  result.innerHTML = str;    
}
```

```html
<form name="tablegen">
  <input type="text" name="grid" id="grid"/>
  <input name="generate" id="gridSize" type="button" value="Generate Grid!" onclick='createTable();'/>
</form>

<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

This is my code and I just can't seem to figure out how to go about this.

Comment: why not just sum all randNumber you calculated and divide by total count?

Comment: So you are looking to get an average of all the random numbers generated?

Comment: If so, use a global variable that keeps track of all the numbers (keep adding to the global variable) and divide by the number the user entered and it will give you the average.

Comment: Yes, the user is determining the size of the grid and when they click the "generate grid" button, the grid is then made with a bunch or random numbers.

Comment: @B.Leigh: I think that is clear. You wrote "i just can't seem to figure out how to go about this". About what?

Comment: Here is a sample fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9f3ne5bo/2/. Is that what you mean? It gives you float also. If you are looking for an integer that can be done also.

Comment: Yeah that's what im looking for but thats giving me a different average. Like if i display a 2x2 grid and the numbers 1, 4, 5, and 39 is showing then it displays an average of 30631.5 when the average should be 12.25

Comment: you probably made a mistake during a calculation, take a look at answers below

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way, just accumulate the randNumber you calculated, then divide by the total number of cells.

```js
var button = document.getElementById('gridSize');

button.onclick = function(e) {
  result = document.getElementById('wrapper');
  num = parseInt(document.getElementById('grid').value);
  var avg = 0;
  var str = "<table border='2'>";

  for (row = 0; row < num; row++) {
    str += "<tr>";
    for (col = 0; col < num; col++) {
      var randNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
      avg += randNumber;
      if (randNumber % 3 === 0) {
        str += '<td style="background: red;">';
      } 
      else if (randNumber % 2 === 0 && !randNumber % 3 === 0) {
        str += '<td style="background: blue;">';
      } 
      else {
          str += "<td>";
      }

      str += randNumber + "</td>";
    }
    str += "</tr>";
  }
  avg /= num*num;
  str = str + "</table>" + "<span>Average is " + avg + "</span>";
  result.innerHTML = str;    
}
```

```html
<form name="tablegen">
  <input type="text" name="grid" id="grid"/>
  <input name="generate" id="gridSize" type="button" value="Generate Grid!" onclick='createTable();'/>
</form>

<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: `avg /= num;` divides by the number in the input, not the total number of cells.

Answer (score 1):

Well, create a variable where you keep summing all generated random numbers.

At the end, get that number and divide by the area of the grid (the number user typed * the number user typed `num*num`)

Like below:

```js
var button = document.getElementById('gridSize');

button.onclick = function(e) {
  var total = 0;
  result = document.getElementById('wrapper');
  num = parseInt(document.getElementById('grid').value);
  var str = "<table border='2'>";

  for (row = 0; row < num; row++) {
    str += "<tr>";
    for (col = 0; col < num; col++) {
      var randNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
      if (randNumber % 3 === 0) {
        str += '<td style="background: red;">';
      } 
      else if (randNumber % 2 === 0 && !randNumber % 3 === 0) {
        str += '<td style="background: blue;">';
      } 
      else {
          str += "<td>";
      }
      total += parseInt(randNumber); 
      str += randNumber + "</td>";
    }
    str += "</tr>";
  }
  str = str + "</table>";
  result.innerHTML = str;    
  console.log("Avg.: ", total/(num*num) || 0)
}
```

```html
<form name="tablegen">
  <input type="text" name="grid" id="grid"/>
  <input name="generate" id="gridSize" type="button" value="Generate Grid!" onclick='createTable();'/>
</form>

<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of additions to what you gave us to start with.

```js
var button = document.getElementById('gridSize');
var total = 0;
var divisor = 0;

button.onclick = function(e) {
  result = document.getElementById('wrapper');
  num = parseInt(document.getElementById('grid').value);
  var str = "<table border='2'>";

  for (row = 0; row < num; row++) {
    str += "<tr>";
    for (col = 0; col < num; col++) {
      var randNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
      total = total+randNumber;
      ++divisor;
      if (randNumber % 3 === 0) {
        str += '<td style="background: red;">';
      } 
      else if (randNumber % 2 === 0 && !randNumber % 3 === 0) {
        str += '<td style="background: blue;">';
      } 
      else {
          str += "<td>";
      }

      str += randNumber + "</td>";
    }
    str += "</tr>";
  }
  str = str + "</table>";
  result.innerHTML = str;
  var average = total / divisor;
  var averageSpan = document.getElementById('average');
  averageSpan.innerText = average;
}
```

```html
<form name="tablegen">
  <input type="text" name="grid" id="grid"/>
  <input name="generate" id="gridSize" type="button" value="Generate Grid!" onclick='createTable();'/>
</form>


Average: <span id="average"></span>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Also a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/775850/

Comment: Clicking two times at "generete grid" breaks the average.

Comment: @CalvinNunes No it doesn't, I just manually calculated the averages of three grids generated in succession, they were all correct.

Answer (score 0):

There are already some good answers. Here is a different approach. I also "cleaned up" the HTML and code a bit:

```js
let button = document.getElementById("generatorButton");

button.onclick = function(e) {
    document.getElementById("grid").innerHTML = createGrid();
    document.getElementById("full-average").innerText = getGridAverage();
    document.getElementById("mod3-average").innerText = getGridAverage(".mod3");
    document.getElementById("mod2-average").innerText = getGridAverage(".mod2");
}

function createGrid()
{
    gridSize = parseInt(document.getElementById('gridSize').value);
    let str = "<table border='2'>";
    for (let row = 0; row < gridSize; row++) {
        str += "<tr>";
        for (let col = 0; col < gridSize; col++) {
            var randNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
            if (randNumber % 3 === 0) {
                str += '<td class="mod3">';
            } 
            else if (randNumber % 2 === 0) {
                str += '<td class="mod2">';
            } 
            else {
                str += "<td>";
            }

            str += randNumber + "</td>";
        }
        str += "</tr>";
    }
    str = str + "</table>";
    return str;
}

function getGridAverage(cssClass)
{
    if (cssClass == undefined) cssClass = "";

    let cells = document.querySelectorAll("#grid td" + cssClass);
    if (cells.length > 0)
    {
        let sum = 0;
        for (const cell of cells)
        {
           sum += parseInt(cell.innerHTML);
        }
        return sum / cells.length;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

```css
.mod3 {
  background-color: red;
}

.mod2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<form name="tablegen">
    <input type="text" id="gridSize" placeholder="Enter grid size (e.g.: 5)" />
    <input type="button" id="generatorButton" value="Generate Grid!" />
</form>

<div id="grid"></div>

<div>Full Average:<span id="full-average">n/a</span></div>

<div>Mod3 (red) Average:<span id="mod3-average">n/a</span></div>

<div>Mod2 (blue) Average:<span id="mod2-average">n/a</span></div>
```

Comment: This is perfect! But what if i wanted to generate the average of all the blue cells and then all the red cells?

Comment: @B.Leigh: Then I would change the `<td style="background: red;">` (and blue accordinlgy) HTML to use a class instead: `<td class="red">` (maybe don't use "red", but a semantic name as class) and then change the `querySelectorAll` parameter to `#grid td.red` for instance, to only consider the red cells. I updated the answer above.